# Xamarin XAML binding to listview variable

Tags: listview, xamarin, binding

How would I make a ImageSource URL that binds ThumbBlobURl and BlobURL to ImageName ?

```
    <ListView 
            x:Name="listView"
            SeparatorVisibility="Default"
            ItemTapped="OnItemTapped"
            IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true" Refreshing="OnRefresh"
          >

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Start" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageName, StringFormat = ThumbBlobURL + '{0}'}" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest = "64"/>
                        <Image Source="{Binding ImageName, StringFormat = BlobURL + '{0}'}" HorizontalOptions="Start" HeightRequest = "64"/>
```

Comment: What are sample values of `ImageName` and `ThumbBlobUrl` or `BlobUrl`? Also can't you create a property which combines there for you already? So just create a property like `public string ThumbnailImage { get{ ThumbBlobURL + ImageName; } }` then your binding can just be `{Binding ThumbnailImage}`

Comment: These are just strings stored in the db e.g:
 abc.jpg
 http://www.azureblobstorage.com/images/thumb
 http://www.azureblobstorage.com/images/

I'm note sure if your solution would work as I dont think you can bind the listView.ItemsSource to multiples sources ?

Comment: From what you are saying I think I see that you don't quite understand how a `ListView` with a `DataTemplate` works. You bind a collection of items to the `ListView` and each item gets evaluated for each cell in the list. So you each cell stands for an object in your collection. Each object in your collection can be different and have different values in their (image) properties. Check out [this](http://www.pauloortins.com/2015/05/05/xamarin-forms-controls-listview/) extensive example

Comment: Ahh cool I see what you mean now. Thanks :)